# Undefined output with prefix operator in C

Tags: c, prefix-operator

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int i=2;
 printf("%d %d\n",++i,++i);
 return 0;
}
```

Output is 4 4 on gcc.
Please explain this output

Comment: You yourself wrote that it is `undefined` in the title. What more is there to explain than that?

Comment: so everytime answers to such questions would be unpredictable?

Comment: @user2492165 yes you can say that..

Comment: You'd better not write code like this. It depends on compilers. You also don't need to struggle with this kind of problems.

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behaviour. The order of evaluation of the function parameters is not defined by the C standard.

Relevant sections: C99 Section 6.5.2.2 Paragraph 10

> The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual
>   arguments, and subexpressions within the actual arguments is
>   unspecified, but there is a sequence point before the actual call.

also in C99 Section 6.5.2.2 Paragraph 10

> There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function
>   designator and the actual arguments but before the actual call. Every
>   evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls)
>   that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the
>   execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately
>   sequenced with respect to the execution of the called function.94)